# Sudden jQuery Failure

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've logged onto a client's site this morning (it's an intranet that monitors vehicle usage etc). jQuery is a decent part of the site but all of a sudden it's failed with these console errors:

> jquery.js:1Uncaught SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token :
>   www.mydomain.com:21Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>   www.mydomain.com:50Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: $ is not defined

The only thing that I've changed in the past week is adding a charset and altering the doctype to:

```
<? header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >
```

I think this might be the problem but removing the header() and DOCTYPE doesn't fix the issue. Any ideas what could be going on?

Edit 1:
Chrome Inspector shows nothing has failed to load.

Edit 2: Head Section

```
<head>
    <title>Intranet</title>
    <link href="/intranet/style/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/intranet/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAb-ZNlr3CQw5Wb5StE921RxSRXiZIiheENMB8Q6Efuo3Cg-x8OhRoSG-6YA6TMItzJlsBO4hkest8jw" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //too much jQuery to post but it's always worked
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Check out Firebug. Is jQuery still getting loaded? Also remove the line break between your PHP code and the doctype declaration

Comment: Checked with Chrome Inspector, edited my question

Comment: Can you show your `head` section? Where is the code that throws the error, in an external file?

Comment: Edited to show it, the first error occurs in the minified jquery file that I've always used?

Comment: From the error message, your jQuery file seems broken. What happens if you open it in the browser?

Comment: You should really specify the full version number (you are currently missing the maintenance release version number) of jQuery UI. Do you know which version was working properly before? If so, switch to that. Also, you can try and load [jQuery from Google's AJAX API](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js) as well and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only serve the file as UTF-8 if it's encoded as UTF-8. Changing the content-type encoding whilst not changing the encoding of the file itself will most certainly break it.

It's important to note that some editors save UTF-8 with [BOM (Byte order mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which can give you alot of headaches. There's no need to use BOM for UTF-8, so use an editor where you can choose to save without BOM.

As I mentioned in my comment above, when loading libraries from [Google AJAX API](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/) you should specify the full version of the library you want to use, otherwise you will eventually run into trouble when changes are introduced into a new maintenance release that can break your existing code. I mention this out of experience ;)

Also, I can see a lot of inconsitencies in your code. I would change to the following:

```
<? header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Intranet</title>
    <link href="/intranet/style/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAb-ZNlr3CQw5Wb5StE921RxSRXiZIiheENMB8Q6Efuo3Cg-x8OhRoSG-6YA6TMItzJlsBO4hkest8jw"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //too much jQuery to post but it's always worked
    </script>
</head>
```

One more thing that is important to note when changing character encoding in PHP: If you use [`setlocale`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) you also need to change it into using a UTF-8 locale. ie. `en_US` to `en_US.UTF-8`, or you might end up with a bunch of �

Answer (score 0):

Changing your doctype is likely to change what rendering mode your browser is in.  If you were in some sort of quirks mode before, you may now be in a more standards compliant mode now (or vice versa). Removing the doctype altogether will cause the browser to guess at which render mode to use or it will use whatever default render mode it has. Try changing the doctype back to its original value.